# Regex to extract a number inside a node format

Tags: java, regex, numbers

I have a string with values of [7^^[http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer,...]](http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer,...%5d) which are derriving from a sparql query. I need a regex to extract only the first numbers next to ^^ everytime for the pattern-matcher.

Can anyone help?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You mean you want to get 7 in this case?

Comment: @usama8800 yes, but if it happens to be also a double number it should also be able to extract them as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse your input using `\\[(.*)\\^\\^.*` and get the first matcher group

As in following code:

```
    String str= "[7^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer,...]";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*)\\^\\^.*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    if(m.matches()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

now you can use `Double.parseDouble` to get a double value.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
String x="7^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\A\\d+").matcher(x);
if (matcher.find()) System.out.println(x.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct, if I can help, I'll mix them up with the following to detect start and end of the string

```
final String str = "[7^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer,...]";
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\[(\\d*)\\^\\^.*$");
final Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```